# How can I get current web request using Vert.x Web?

Tags: hibernate, orm, kotlin, vert.x, reactive

I am writing a project using Hibernate (JPA) + Vert.x Web (Kotlin) and I need to bind EntityManager to Web Request, I mean I want to create EntityManager per each web request. I need to get current web request from VertX using some static method (object in Kotlin). Is there a way to do that? Or am I going the wrong way since VertX is reactive?

Answer (score 1):

What you normally should do is initialize EntityManager in one Verticle, and handle web requests in the other. Communicate using EventBus. Something along those lines (code is not exact):

```
public class DBVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
   public void start() throws Exception {
      EntityManager em = ...; //init your EM   

      vertx.eventBus().<String>consumer("some_description_of_what_you_want").handler(h -> {
          ResultSet rs = em.doSomeQuery();
          h.reply(rs);
      });
   }
}

public class WebVerticle extends AbstractVerticle { 
   public void start() throws Exception {
       HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
       Router router = Router.router(vertx);

       router.get("/").handler(ctx -> {
          vertx.eventBus().<String>send("some_description_of_what_you_want", "maybe payload", result -> {
           if (result.succeeded()) {
              ctx.end(result);
           }
        });
       });

       server.handler(router::accept);
   }
}
```

You can see an example here: https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/tree/master/spring-examples/spring-example/src/main/java/io/vertx/examples/spring/verticle

Comment: It is good answer! But I need to sacrifice my Repository pattern to use this method: I have to send e.g. the Entity Type and Id and expect the verticle to return the item which the id is its key! But I am now using a BaseRepository as parent and several Repository classes for DB actions. How can I mix your way with repository?

Comment: @Kamyar In practice, you would wrap each of your repositories into a verticle. So instead of "some_description_of_what_you_want" you would send "apples" or "bananas", and it would go to specific repo. Also notice you can send any payload through EventBus, so you can send object IDs, for example.

Comment: As you already know, each repository has many actions, sometimes more than simple CRUD! Even in your case, I must send my favorite action (add, remove, edit..) in some way. I think making so many Verticles is a code smell!

Comment: Probably I didn't explain myself correctly. You don't have to create verticle per method. You create verticle per your Repository. Name of the action is the name agreed with repository. Payload may be JSON of the following form: `{"action":"DELETE","id":123}`. Your repository verticle can fetch this object, and call whichever method you declared in repo.

Comment: But your solution is not so great! It is also a code smell IMHO!

Comment: I wrote the code as you recommended! I also wrote a MessageCodec to handle inter-verticle messages. Anyway, I have still the problem: the entityManager is now never closed! When should I close it? Should I bind it to web request or not? Binding it to verticle instance is right?

Comment: You have stop() method in your Verticle for that.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to initialize your entity manager per request and make it available at any handler later on. In this case you could do something like:

```
public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
  public void start() throws Exception {

    HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();
    Router router = Router.router(vertx);

    router.route().handler(ctx -> {
      EntityManager em = ...; //init your EM
      ctx.put("em", em);
      ctx.next();
      // as of this moment the entity manager is available for all
      // handlers in the current request by the key "em" 
    }

    router.get("/").handler(ctx -> {
      EntityManager em = ctx.get("em");
      // use it as you would...
      ctx.response().end(/* your response here... */);
    });

    server.handler(router::accept);
  }
}
```

Be aware that this code never closes/disposes your entity manager and you might need to add a end handler/exception handler somewhere to close it.

Comment: I tried it but in this case I have to pass the entityManager to my repositories which is not my favorite way to do it!

Comment: BTW the only thing I get this way is centralizing entity manager instantiation which I can do using IoC instead! And I can omit your way and instead start creating object at first line of each handler and closing at end line! the first line here is replaced with context and the last must be replaced with next() to let another one close the entity manager! Do you think your way is useful yet?

Comment: You said you wanted an entity manager per request so the example above does that for you. It also allows you to access the manager from other handlers even if declared on other class files.